# Simple view produces internal server error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Controller action look for a job post. If job not found, just return simple `View("NotFound")`:

```
[Route("jobs/{id}")]
public ActionResult Detail(int id) {
    Job job = JobRepository.GetByIdDetail(id);
    if (job == null)
        return View("NotFound");
}
```

NotFound.cshtml:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Job not found";
  ViewBag.Subtitle = "I’m sorry, it looks like this job has been closed.";
}
<main>
  <div class="container">
    @ViewBag.Subtitle
  </div>
</main>
```

Instead of `View`, I got:

> Internal server error 500

with stack trace:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Detail(Int32)' in 'CeeVee.Controllers.JobsController

Why it won't just show the `NotFound` view? Why is it still searching for the `id` parameter, which is no longer relevant in this case?

**UPDATE:**
Dont understand why it wont return simple stupid View.
Even when I add action method, the same error occurs.

```
[Route("jobs/notfound")]
        public ActionResult NotFound ()
        {
                return  View("NotFound");
        }
```

**/jobs/notfound** gives Error 500 ?!?!?!?!??!? '{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}' Whaaat object ???

**UPDATE 2**: Global.asax.cs
[image]

I WOULD LIKE TO CLOSE THIS QUESTION :( THE PROBLEM WAS IN MY LAYOUT.CSHTML. Sorry guys..

Comment: Because this is what you told it to do ;) Post the route or link that you used to get this error.

Comment: but it wont show NotFound view. It throws internal server error.

Comment: We cannot debug your code, you're the only one who can do that. So do it and tell us which line is throwing that exception.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Updated post contains error.

Comment: I WOULD LIKE TO CLOSE THIS QUESTION: NO CORRECT ANSWER :( THE PROBLEM WAS IN MY LAYOUT.CSHTML. Sorry guys..

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller code to this:

```
[Route("jobs/{id}")]
public ActionResult Detail(int? id) {
    if(!id.HasValue) //you can also add '|| id.Value > 0' if your ids cannot be zero
        return View("NotFound");
    Job job = JobRepository.GetByIdDetail(id.Value);
    if (job == null)
        return View("NotFound");
}
```